# Извлечь цену выбранного вариативного товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте есть вариативные товары, мне нужно извлечь цену выбранной вариации товара и передать её методом POST при нажатии кнопки. Я прочитал много информации в интернете, но не нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. С простыми товарами проблем нет, не знаю как извлечь цену на выбранный товар. Помогите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть простые функции для получения цены вариативного товара.

```
$min_price_regular = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
$min_price_sale = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
$max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
$min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );
```

Второй аргумент - включать ли налоги в расчёт.

Чтобы получить все вариации товара, используйте

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

Возвращает массив вариаций товара.

Цены указаны внутри каждой вариации, например:

```
$available_variations[0]->display_price;
$available_variations[0]->display_regular_price;
```

**Update**

В ходе обсуждения выяснилось, что цена отправляется формой при нажатии кнопки.

Измените html-код кнопки таким образом, чтобы отправлялась правильная цена:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="button-rassrochka" onclick="
var price=jQuery('form.cart span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html().split('<')[0].replace(' ', '');
price = price * jQuery('form.cart .quantity input').val();
jQuery('input[name=sum]').val(price);
return true;
" return="">Подать заявку</button>
```

Этот код при клике на кнопку считывает текущую html-цену товара из `span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount`, удаляет из неё html-код, удаляет пробелы, записывает цену в `input[name=sum]` вашей формы, и возвращает `true`, чтобы форма отправилась.

Comment: Это я в курсе, на странице товара, а не в корзине, как отправить цену выбранной вариации? я не силен в php вообще

Comment: чтобы было понятно на практике, страница товара http://ghibli.info/shop/ghibli-round-45-sd-55-bc-touch/ банку для оформления рассрочки нужно отправить методом пост цену выбранного товара, пока смог сделать из корзины, чтобы правильно работало, а тут голову сломал уже, не получается

Comment: Это работает везде. Покажите php код, которым вы формируете #contact_form_pop

Comment: сейчас я просто беру цену первого товара <input name="sum" value="<?php echo $product->get_display_price();?>" type="hidden">

Comment: Я уж вам вроде все расписал. Смотрите последние три строчки. И ещё - где вы это формируете? При создании страницы или в ajax? Какой код работает при клике на кнопку?

Comment: при клике на кнопку работает код <form action="http://ghibli.info.ru/test22.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="shopId" value="global" type="hidden"/><input name="showcaseId" value="ghibli" type="hidden"/>
<input name="sum" value="<?php echo $product->get_display_price();?>" type="hidden">

Comment: вы мне написали "Возвращает массив вариаций товара." а как отправить цену именно выбранной вариации? я не понимаю

Comment: в ручную понимаю $available_variations[0] [1] [2], а автоматически?

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что форму вы формируете в php-коде, где жестко ставите цену одной из вариаций, а вариацию выбираете по радио-кнопке. Ваша форма ничего не знает о динамических изменениях на сайте. Вам надо сделать js-код, который 1) перехватит событие submit 2) подставит в `input name="sum"` выбранное радиокнопкой значение, 3) отправит форму

Comment: Сделал такой код и дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень помогли, сам бы не догадался

Comment: А подскажите, если покупатель выбрал несколько товаров в <input type="number"> как перемножить на количество в этом скрипте?

Comment: Ну так же, прочитать поле количество и умножить

Comment: только что заметил, если в корзине есть товары, при нажатии на кнопку он берет цену первого товара из корзины ><

Comment: С корзиной вообще другая история

Comment: и что мне делать? ваш совет получается не рабочий. проблема возникает на странице товара, а не в корзине. а данные берутся из корзины почему то

Comment: На странице товара нет никакой корзины. В вашем вопросе нет слова корзина. Мой совет точно работает на странице товара. При чем тут корзина вообще?

Comment: Хотите узнать, как отправить со страницы корзины - задайте новый вопрос. Потому что там все вообще не так надо делать.

Comment: Всего-то надо было уточнить элемент. Добавил `form.cart ` в ответ.

Comment: Добавил еще одну строчку в код `price = price * jQuery('form.cart .quantity input').val();` для умножения цены на количество. Ну элементарные же действия. Я вам дал ответ не как законченное решение всех ваших проблем, а как руководство к действию. Главное в нем было - захват цены в jQuery. Дальше уже вам самому надо было подключать свои знания, чтобы добавить детали: количество и изолирование элемента от мини-корзины в шапке сайта.

Comment: вы меня не поняли, зайдите на сайт, добавьте любой товар в корзину, теперь перейдите на страницу любого другого товара и попробуйте оформить кредит, в заявку перейдет цена товара из корзины, а не цена товара на котором нажимаем кнопку...

Comment: Я вас прекрасно понял, и добавил код в ответ

Comment: мне не хватает знаний сделать изолирование цены, с умножением как нибудь попробую разобраться. в любом случае спасибо, буду изучать, возможно через пол года я найду ответ)

Comment: Да вы просто читайте ВСЕ комментарии. И возьмите ГОТОВЫЙ КОД уже. Ну неужели трудно его сравнить с тем, что на сайте?

Comment: выше код исправили, я не сразу заметил, теперь все работает, поищу баги

Comment: помоги пожалуйста, когда в корзине пусто и добавляешь простой товар - не передается sum. если в корзине лежит любой товар, то все работает

Comment: задал условия для простого и вариативного товара и все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что вопрос давний, но кому то ответ явно пригодятся 
1) в файл variable.php, вставляем после открsвающего тэга form скрытый инпут

```
<input type="hidden" id="w_new_price" name="w_new_price" value="">
```

2) Любым удобным способом на jquery в него передаём значение цены.

3) В function.php добавляем этот код

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'add_custom_cart_item_data_product', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data_product( $cart_item_data, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['w_new_price'] ) )
        $cart_item_data['w_new_price'] = $_POST['w_new_price'];
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_cart_item_price_product', 10, 1 );
function set_custom_cart_item_price_product( $wc_cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! empty($cart_item['w_new_price']))
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['w_new_price']);
    }
}
```

Теперь для товаров, цена будет браться из этого инпута, в том случае, если он не пустой